# How can I automatically resend a Slack message every X days in a public channel if it hasn't gotten any reply?

Tags: slack, slackbot

How can I automatically resend a Slack message every X days in a public channel if it hasn't gotten any reply?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a reminder in a channel to do this:

```
/remind #general to “respond to [this message](link)” every Monday at 9am
```